# Regular Expression - +/- sign and decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, html

I am trying to create a regular expression for decimal number and at the same time "-" or "+" sign to be optional at the start.

There are a lot of information about this, so I finished with this:

```
/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

So, I have tested this in the console using the `test()` function and it is working perfectly.

My question is more about where to do this check:

- if the check is on `keypress` event I am able to use `preventDefault()` in order to "consume" the incorrect symbols but I am retrieving the text like this and have no access to the last entered symbol - `$(event.target).val()`
- if the check is on `keyup` event I have access to the whole text, but I am not able to remove the incorrect symbol, because I do not know which is it, and where it was put in (using the mouse it can be put in the start or in the middle of a valid string)

I need to check combination of symbols, not validate the symbols only. For example:

```
- //invalid
- 1 //valid
1. //invalid
1.2 //valid
```

So, I guess I should the check when the whole sting is entered, but then, how two remove the incorrect characters? Removing the whole string on when it is invalid does not look right.

Comment: That regex is too verbose, `/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/` is shorter and equivalent.

Comment: @Jon, thanks, you are right. It just take me a while to understand that the issues I am having are connecting with when the check is done, not regular expression itself, so I have changed it a lot. I will correct it.

Comment: I would say find a way to prompt the user of 'invalid number' after they try entering it and make them re-enter the number, or have something on the side of the entry box with 'valid' or 'invalid' showing (the check will then be done after each key press and change from valid to invalid and vice versa as more chars are entered). I don't know enough JS to help there though!

Comment: @Jerry: I agree with you. [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6SCjw/) is how I would do it. This will tell the user if there is something wrong with the value as they keep entering it.

Comment: @Harry Oh hey, that's awesome!

Comment: @Harry This is very nice idea. Please, give it as answer.

Comment: @gotqn: Would you mind if I add HTML5 and CSS tags to this question mate? My answer has a sample using HTML5 & CSS also and adding the tags might be helpful for future searches.

Comment: @Harry No, go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below is one possible way to tell the user if there is anything wrong with their input as they keep entering. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6SCjw/) for a sample demo.

In addition, we can also add a `<div>` listing the allowed characters/format. This in addition to letting the user know that there is something wrong, will also tell them what forms a valid input.

**HTML:**

```
<input id='ip' type='text'/>
```

**JS:**

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^[+-]?\s*\d+(\.\d+)?$/);

document.getElementById('ip').onkeyup = function(){
    var inputVal = this.value;
    if(!(regex.test(inputVal))) this.className='err';
    else this.className='noerr';
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.noerr{
    color: green;
}
.err{
    color: red;
}
```

**Note:** HTML5 has inbuilt ways to validate input and also has pseudo-classes like `:invalid` and `:valid` to do the same as what the above example does. If you can use HTML5, try [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/6SCjw/1/). The second input field is done using HTML5 (no JS required).

**HTML5:**

```
<input id='iphtml5' pattern='[+-]?\s*\d+(\.\d+)?' type='text' />
```

**CSS:**

```
#iphtml5:valid{
    color: green;
}
#iphtml5:invalid{
    color: red;
}
```